# How to recognize Java in CMD

Tags: java, cmd, corretto

After installing Java Corretto 17 from Java 8, java-version is not recognized in CMD. Prior java projects are not compiling in my IDE.

I uninstalled prior JDK 8 and installed Corretto. I updated the path in my system and environmental variables, but to no avail. I am able to update each project individually with the Corretto in my IDE's project structure. I'm looking for a system wide solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the instructions here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/windows-7-install.html

Specifically step 4:

> Once the install wizard is finished, set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`
> environment variables.
>
> Set `JAVA_HOME` to the installation location, noting that the directory
> contains the currently-installed version. For example, if the default
> directory is used for 17.0.0, then set `JAVA_HOME` as C:\Program
> Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk17.0.0_35.
>
> Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the current `PATH` variable.

Based on the symptoms you reported, it seems that you did not set `PATH` correctly ...

---

> I'm looking for a system wide solution.

Make sure that you set the "system" versions of the variables.  But if there are user / account specific overrides for `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` they will need to be updated also.  Note that you *may* need to restart your CMD shell to pick up changes that you made to environment variables via the GUI.  That's just the way that environment variables work ...